# Password protect Hadoop NameNode Web UI on port 50070

Tags: apache, .htaccess, hadoop

Hadoop's NameNode has a Web UI on port 50070 (http://localhost:50070) which is always accessible via a browser. I want to password protect that entire directory via basic authentication through either .htaccess or httpd.conf. However all my efforts were so far useless. Here's the examples I tried with:

```
<VirtualHost *:50070>
  DocumentRoot /usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-hdfs/webapps/hdfs
  <Location /explorer.html>
    AuthUserFile path_to_passwords_file
    AuthName "Password Protected"
    AuthType Basic
    Require user username
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

OR

```
<Directory "/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop-hdfs/webapps/hdfs">
      Options +Indexes
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Documents"
      AuthUserFile path_to_passwords_file
      Require user username
      AllowOverride None
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
</Directory>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to put password protection on that page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Jetty already had such functionality which is described here:

[Securing Hadoop (HDP) Web UI Component's](https://streever.atlassian.net/wiki/display/HADOOP/2014/03/06/Securing+Hadoop+(HDP)+Web+UI+Component's)

Thanks to everybody who looked into this!

Answer (score 1):

Config samples from your question are from apache web server. NameNode Web UI doesn't use apache web server. It uses jetty which also supports basic authentication. You might want to search for something like "jetty basic auth" to get started.